# Redis publish and subscription not working on dynamic keys

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, livechat, predis

my requirement is to publish message for specific user.

Controller

```
$messageQueueKey=(string)$receiver; (receiver_id)
$redis->publish($messageQueueKey, json_encode($data));
```

Server.js //Node js

```
  var handshakeData = socket.request;
  var messageQueueKey=handshakeData._query['userid'];

  clients[socket.id] = socket;

  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe(messageQueueKey);
 // redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message)
  {
      var data = JSON.parse(message);
      if(typeof connectedClients[data['receiver']] === 'undefined'){}
      else
      {
        connectedClients[data['receiver']].socket.emit(channel, message);  
      } 
  });
```

However my code works for hard coded key 'message' but receivers receives multiple messages that is why i want to publish and subscribe each user on different keys based on their auth id

Answer (score 0):

That's fine! if the user is receiving multiple message you can ignore the one :P